# PHP prepared statement concatenate: "comma", "and", and "period" from while loop

Tags: php, arrays, prepared-statement, concatenation

I'm trying to build a sentence from a MySQL query.  I believe I have the concatenate part working, as I've substituted a static array in.  Might anyone guide me in the right direction as to what my while loop would look like to produce the needed array?  How can I create an associative array from my mysql statement?

```
$query = "SELECT name, dob FROM children WHERE personal_id = ?";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['mysqlID']);
$statement->bind_result($name, $dob);
$statement->execute();

// Store the results
$statement->store_result();

// Get the number of rows
$num_of_rows = $statement->num_rows;


**//I believe my problem lies in this array ?**
$m_children = [];
while ($statement->fetch()) {
  $m_children[] =  $name;
  $m_children[] .=  $dob;
}

$num_children = intval($num_of_rows);
$children = [];

foreach ($m_children as $k => $v) {
  $dob = strtotime($dob[$k]);
  $children[] = "$v, born on {$dob}";
}

$tmp = array_pop($children);

  if ($num_children > 1) {
    $children_type = 'children';
    $children = join(', ', $children) . ' and ' . $tmp;
  } else {
    $children_type = 'child';
    $children = $tmp;
  }

$children = "<p>I have the following ". $children_type .": ". $children .".</p>";
```

Comment: How can I create an associative array from my mysql statement?

Comment: Example of the desired output?

Comment: Thanks.  Database is returning a name and a date of birth.  I need the sentence to read.  'Name' was born on 'date', 'name' was born on 'date', and 'name' was born on 'date'.  And if one result just end with a period.

Comment: This code is all over the place.. Where do `$statement2` and the `$dob` array in the foreach even come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall your code looks okay. The grammatical parts are certainly solid (pop the last element, join the rest with commas etc...)

As you suspect, your problem code is that part that you've marked.

```
//I believe my problem lies in this array ?
$m_children = [];
while ($statement2->fetch()) {
  $m_children[] =  $name;
  $m_children[] .=  $dob;
}

$num_children = intval($num_of_rows);
$children = [];

foreach ($m_children as $k => $v) {
  $dob = strtotime($dob[$k]);
  $children[] = "$v, born on {$dob}";
}
```

---

Here's a suggested improvement:

```
$children = [];
while( $statement2->fetch()) {
    $children[] = $name." born on ".date("d/M/Y",strtotime($dob));
}
$num_children = count($children);
```

There's no need to do two passes on the data, and you will need to format out the date of birth (otherwise you just get a timestamp). This code can then continue on to your grammatical formatting, which seems just fine to me.